# SurfaceView in Fragment - on top of everything

Tags: java, android, surfaceview, game-development

I have two fragments which I need to add at same time (both to be in the fragmentmanager in same time). In the second one I have a SurfaceView that draws some logic on the canvas. But when the first, initial Fragment is shown, I see the drawing from the canvas OVER it. The ZOrder is set onTop (setZOrderOnTop(true)).

Is there way to tell it NOT to draw over the first fragment..? If I remove the setZOrderOnTop(true) call I get black background of the surfaceview which covers the Background of the layout where it persists.

Thanks